# Cannot get Array.prototype.includes to work in Typescript 2.0

Tags: typescript

I am using typescript@next (version 2.1.0-dev.20160812 to be specific).

I am getting errors when trying to use Arrays.prototype.includes.

For instance this code

```
let myItems: Array<string>;
let exists: boolean = myItems.includes('blah');
```

Generates the following error:

```
Property 'includes' does not exist on type 'string[]'.at line 124 col 26
```

This is my tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "es6",
    "target": "es6",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "ts-build",
    "jsx": "preserve"
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

Comment: According to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes, includes has been added to ES2016 (AKA ES7), and you're targetting ES6, so you shouldn't use that method (or you need a polyfill). You could just use `myItems.indexOf('blah') >= 0`

Comment: @JBNizet does that mean I should be targetting ES7? I am using babel to transpile to es5

Comment: @JBNizet looks like you cannot target es7. There are typings for Array.prototype.includes in TS@Next. I am not sure why this wouldn't work yet.

Answer (score 17):

I fixed this by adding lib:["es2016", "dom"] to the compiler options in tsconfig.json

Answer (score 2):

You can add "es2016.array.include" to the compilerOptions

Comment: When should I polyfill ``import 'core-js/es6/array/includes';`` vs ``import 'core-js/es7/array/includes';``

Answer (score 1):

I added `lib:["es2017", "dom"]` to `compilerOptions` in tsconfig.json. 
For more clarification, check out this [github issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/2340)